# Google Cloud IAM - How does the authentication works between GCP resources | Step By Step Sequence Diagram

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-iam, identity-management

Our Services are hosted in GCP and we are using CloudRun,CloudSQL,Pubsub,Storage GCP resources.
Access to these resources are managed by defining the IAM roles to corresponding service accounts.

I would like to understand how and when IAM Policy evaluation and validation happens in the gcp resource to resource communication. for example, While cloud run connecting to pub-sub topic to publish events, How and When the the CloudRun service account bindings are validated ?

Please help to understand the step by step sequence diagram about the IAM Policy evaluation and validation in the gcp resource to resource communication.

Comment: Start here https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/oauth2/service-account#authorizingrequests

Comment: Thanks, this gives the information about adding the GoogleCredential at client service side, any idea how, when and by whom these GoogleCredentials and IAM roles of the service account will be validated ?.

Here Who does the IAM Policy evaluation and allows the communication.

Comment: At the time you call the API you're making the request. Google will check if you have the permissions to make the action you're requesting.

Comment: Your question is too broad. Study each resource and review its supported authorization requirements. For example, Cloud Run uses OIDC Identity Tokens, Cloud Storage supports multiple methods. In summary, you must understand OAuth in Google Cloud and the differencees between API Keys, OAuth Access Tokens, and OIDC Identity Tokens, and how they are used.

Comment: @JohnHanley, Thanks, does GCP have common service/resource which acts as proxy/gateway for all resources which validates the tokens and do the IAM Policy evaluation ?

Comment: @Ferregina, Thanks, Here what I'm trying to understand is which resource do the the token validation and IAM Policies evaluation after making the API call.

underneath is there any central/common service which acts as proxy/gateway in all resources communication for the  token validation and IAM Policy evaluation. If yes, what is the name of the service ?

Comment: That's something you will never know. At most we can know the flow it takes, but the internal system that checks that is only know by GCP (Google). At most we can say that is IAM and that's all.